# PySpark dataframe sample description

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a PySpark DataFrame with 5 million rows and want to get a description of randomly selected subset.

When I generate two different samples of the same fraction I get the same result.

> sample_1 = df.sample(fraction=0.03, seed=None)

```
sample_1.describe().show(100)
+-------+--------------------+
|summary|            row_name|
+-------+--------------------+
|  count|              160933|
|   mean|2.921313376194685...|
| stddev| 3.50815577432219E13|
|    min|            10111444|
|    max|            99955723|
+-------+--------------------+
```

> sample_2 = df.sample(fraction=0.03, seed=None)

```
sample_2.describe().show(100)

+-------+--------------------+
|summary|            row_name|
+-------+--------------------+
|  count|              160933|
|   mean|2.921313376194685...|
| stddev| 3.50815577432219E13|
|    min|            10111444|
|    max|            99955723|
+-------+--------------------+
```

> ```
> sample_1 == sample_2
> False
> ```

How could the description of two different dataframes be the same?

> SparkContext().version = '2.4.4'

Comment: How about changing the seed at each call ?

Comment: I've tried it but the result is the same.

Comment: Just tested the same, and I am getting different results everytime I sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial guess would be that the `seed` is the same.

If you don't care about reproducibility use a random seed for each sampling.
If you want reproducibility use a constant, but different, seed for each sampling.

Regarding the equality, there might be something happening behind the scenes in the way Spark compares dataframes.

What happens when you run something like:

```
sample_1.except(sample_2).isEmpty
```

Comment: I am infact getting different descriptions using the same code (i.e. with `seed=None`)

Comment: Thanks for responses. Now it works.
But I'm still not sure if that was related to seed, because `seed=None` is the same as random seed.